# calculate how many leap days between two dates

Tags: c, time, datediff

I have written this code down, my object of the program is to calculate the minutes between two given dates and time.
lets say the difference in minute between:

```
14/1/2016 23:18
and
14/1/2004 23:18
is:
6,311,520.00 minutes
```

this is the code i have wrote:

i have some bug in the calculation, from what i found my problem is at most 1440 minute difference from the correct answer - checked by excel.
i think my problem is in the calculation of the LEAP DAYS between the two dates:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    typedef struct {
        int year;
        int month;
        int day;
        int hour;
        int minute;
        int second;     
    }time;
    time time1,time2;

long calcTime(time,time);
int calcDaysFromStart(int,int);
int leapcheck(int);

int main()
{

    printf("Hello\n");
    printf("For calculating the difference between two times:\n");
    printf("Enter the date for first time:\n");
    printf("Enter day:\n");
    scanf("%d",&time1.day);
    printf("Enter month:\n");
    scanf("%d",&time1.month);
    printf("Enter year:\n");
    scanf("%d",&time1.year);
    printf("Enter the exact hour for first time:\n");
    printf("Enter the hour:\n");
    scanf("%d",&time1.hour);
    printf("Enter the minutes:\n");
    scanf("%d",&time1.minute);
    printf("Enter the seconds:\n");
    scanf("%d",&time1.second);
    printf("-----------------------------------\n");
    printf("Enter the date for second time:\n");
    printf("Enter day:\n");
    scanf("%d",&time2.day);
    printf("Enter month:\n");
    scanf("%d",&time2.month);
    printf("Enter year:\n");
    scanf("%d",&time2.year);
    printf("Enter the exact hour for first time:\n");
    printf("Enter the hour:\n");
    scanf("%d",&time2.hour);
    printf("Enter the minutes:\n");
    scanf("%d",&time2.minute);
    printf("Enter the seconds:\n");
    scanf("%d",&time2.second);
    printf("-----------------------------------\n");
    printf("-----------------------------------\n");
    printf("The first time is: %d:%d:%d %d/%d/%d\n", time1.hour ,time1.minute ,time1.second ,time1.day, time1.month ,time1.year);
    printf("The second time is: %d:%d:%d %d/%d/%d\n", time2.hour ,time2.minute ,time2.second ,time2.day, time2.month ,time2.year);
    printf("The Difference between the two times in minutes is:%ld\n", calcTime(time1,time2));
    return 1;   
}


long calcTime(time time1,time time2)
{
    long t1,t2,totalDiff;
    long yearDiffeInMinutes = 0;
    int leapt1, leapt2,leapAdd;
    leapt1 = leapcheck(time1.year);
    leapt2 = leapcheck(time2.year);
    int daysFromStartt1, daysFromStartt2;
    daysFromStartt1 = calcDaysFromStart(time1.month,leapt1);
    daysFromStartt2 = calcDaysFromStart(time2.month,leapt2);
    t1 = time1.minute+time1.hour*60+time1.day*1440+daysFromStartt1*1440;
    t2 = time2.minute+time2.hour*60+time2.day*1440+daysFromStartt2*1440;

    if (time1.year>time2.year)
    {
        leapAdd = (time1.year-time2.year)/4;
        if ((leapt1==1) && (time1.month<3))
            leapAdd--;
        if((leapt2==1) && (time2.month>2))
            leapAdd--;
        printf("THE PARAM leapApp IS:%d\n",leapAdd);
        yearDiffeInMinutes = ((time1.year-time2.year)*525600+leapAdd*1440);
        totalDiff = yearDiffeInMinutes+(t1-t2);
        printf("The first time is bigger\n");
        return totalDiff;
    }
    else if(time2.year>time1.year)
    {
        leapAdd = (time2.year-time1.year)/4;
        if ((leapt2==1) && (time2.month<3))
            leapAdd--;
        if((leapt1==1) && (time1.month>2))
            leapAdd--;
        yearDiffeInMinutes = ((time2.year-time1.year)*525600+leapAdd*1440);
        totalDiff = yearDiffeInMinutes+(t2-t1);
        printf("The second time is bigger\n");
        return totalDiff; 
    }
    else if(t1>t2)/**both times are in the same year**/
    {
        printf("The first time is bigger\n");
        if ((leapt1==1) && (time1.month>2))
            if(time2.month<2)
                return (t1-t2+1440);
        return(t1-t2);
    }
    else if(t2>t1)
    {
        printf("The second time is bigger\n");
        if ((leapt2==1) && (time2.month>2))
            if(time1.month<2)
                return (t2-t1+1440);
        return (t2-t1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Both times are equals\n");
        return 0;
    }
}


/**check if the year is leap, return 0 if not a leap and 1 if a leap**/
int leapcheck(int year)
{
    if(year%400==0 || (year%100!=0 && year%4==0))
    {
        printf("THE YEAR %d IS LEAP\n",year);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("THE YEAR %d is NOT LEAP\n",year);
    return 0;
}



/**clalculate how many days past from start ofthe year**/
int calcDaysFromStart(int month, int leap)
{
    if (month==1)
        return 0;
    else if (month==2)
        return 31;
    else if (month==3)
        return (59+leap);
    else if (month==4)
        return (90+leap);
    else if (month==5)
        return (120+leap);
    else if (month==6)
        return (151+leap);
    else if (month==7)
        return (181+leap);
    else if (month==8)
        return (212+leap);
    else if (month==9)
        return (243+leap);
    else if (month==10)
        return (273+leap);
    else if (month==11)
        return (304+leap);
    else if (month==12)
        return (334+leap);
    else return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick fix for your example would be to add the following line in both `if` and `else`:

```
if(leapt1==1 && leapt2==1)
    leapAdd++;
```

But this code will fail for bigger intervals (which include 100 and 400 years leap exceptions). So, I suggest you to rewrite this part of code; for example you can iterate through each of the year in the interval and check if it leap or common, with your special casing for start and end of interval).

Answer (score 5):

The computation

```
leapAdd = (time1.year-time2.year)/4;
```

is wrong. There was a leap year between 2003 and 2005, but this would ignore it. Also, a span of 13 years can include three or four leap years without hitting the century-complication.

The correct code would be

```
leapAdd = time1.year/4 - time2.year/4      // how many Caesarian leap years
        - time1.year/100 + time2.year/100  // Centuries
        + time1.year/400 - time2.year/400; // last correction.
```

(with swapped roles if `time2.year > time1.year`).

Also,

```
t1 = time1.minute+time1.hour*60+time1.day*1440+daysFromStartt1*1440;
```

overcounts. On the first of the month, there is no complete day to be added, so it should be

```
(time1.day-1)*1440
```

and similarly `(time1.hour-1)*60`, pedantically, also for the minutes. Since the overcount is constant, that doesn't affect the computation of time differences, though.

Answer (score 2):

There's a standard library function to do this.

```
time_t seconds_begin, seconds_end;
struct tm breakdown;

breakdown.tm_year = 2004 - 1900;
breakdown.tm_mon = 0; /* january */
breakdown.tm_mday = 14;
breakdown.tm_hour = 23;
breakdown.tm_min = 18;

seconds_begin = mktime( & breakdown );

breakdown.tm_year = 2016 - 1900;

seconds_end = mktime( & breakdown );

printf( "%.2f minutes", (seconds_end - seconds_begin) / 60. );
```

https://ideone.com/D8djMo

> 6311520.00 minutes

On a Unix system, I would suppose this to be more reliable than Excel.

Comment: i know this standard library function, but the mission is to write this without using those ready functions...

Comment: This also fails (at least on many systems) for dates outside quite a narrow range.

Comment: @TextGeek Elaborate, please.

Comment: Many systems store time internally, as a 31-bit signed number of seconds from the start of 1970. This only reaches from about 1902-2038, so any date outside that is iffy. Some libraries in some languages and platforms also fail for negatives, so fail even for 1969. Best to test before trusting....